# Regex react question, can't get the regex to properly select my ahref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm super new to react and trying to make this work. So long story short, I've got to make data from another site be rendered as html on the react front end for just hyperlinks. I'm not allowed to use dangerously set innerhtml for security reasons. My question is I've manage to get the links working but now I need to pull the sentences before the   tags. What I've set up is the splitter below to split where the   is before and after. However, for the life of me I can only get it to work on the first two hyperlinks. I think something may be wrong with agex. Any help would be much appreciated!

```html
  const splitter = match.match(
                  /(<a href=")?(https?|www)[^\s]*(.*<\/a>)?/gi
                )![0];
                const paredPlainText = match.split(new RegExp(splitter));
                result.push(paredPlainText[0]);
                result.push(link);
                result.push(paredPlainText[1]);
```

Hi just to add to what Drew commented, I want this as an example. This is the input text

This is some text `<a href="google.com">Google.com</a>` Some after text.

So my method is matching the regex  for this `<a href="google.com">Google.com</a>`  and spitting back the before this and after this as I've already wrote the methods for the links to be displayed. Hope this clears this up. Basically I want it to look like this

This is some text `Google.com` Some after text.

Comment: Please include what your expected output should be. A good set of example input-output would be nice.

Comment: Hi sorry @DrewReese . I've edited my question above

Comment: Please PLEASE consider using something else to parse HTML, e.g.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser
It will make your life much easier.

I beg you to read this
https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Comment: Thanks @possum for the advice! I know it's a very weird question but this is just a really weird request that I'm just trying to work around.